# Group and Sum Multiple Columns without Pandas

Tags: python, list, grouping, aggregate

I have a list that contains multiple columns, and I need to group and sum rows based on two columns. Can I do this without using a Pandas dataframe?

I have a dataset in a list like this:

```
User   Days  Project
Dave   3     Red
Dave   4     Red
Dave   2     Blue
Sue    4     Red
Sue    1     Red
Sue    3     Yellow
```

Specifically:
`[[Dave, 3, Red], [Dave, 4, Red], [Dave, 2, Blue], [Sue, 4, Red], [Sue, 1, Red], [Sue, 3, Yellow]]`

What I want to do is output on the same line some totals like this:

```
User   Days  Project   UserDays  ProjectDaysPerUser
Dave   3     Red       9              7
Dave   4     Red       9              7
Dave   2     Blue      9              2
Sue    4     Red       8              5
Sue    1     Red       8              5
Sue    3     Yellow    8              3
```

So I'm trying to group twice to get the "**ProjectDaysPerUser**", first by user, then by project. It's this double grouping that's throwing me off.

Is there an easy way to do this without creating a Panda dataframe?

Comment: If your dataset is not panda, then how does it looks like? a list of lists?

Comment: Updated post to show the list of lists structure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below script is using groupby and appending the result of the sum to the list.

```
from itertools import groupby
data = [['Dave', 3, 'Red'], ['Dave', 4, 'Red'], ['Dave', 2, 'Blue'], ['Sue', 4, 'Red'], ['Sue', 1, 'Red'], ['Sue', 3, 'Yellow']]
new_data, final = [], []
userDays=[[k, sum(v[1] for v in g)] for k, g in groupby(data, key = lambda x: x[0])]
projuserDays=[[k, sum(v[1] for v in g)] for k, g in groupby(data, key = lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))]
#add userDays and projectuserdays
for d in data:
    for u in userDays:
        if d[0]==u[0]:
            d.append(u[1])
            new_data.append(d)
    for p in projuserDays:
        if d[0]==p[0][0] and d[2]==p[0][1]:
            d.append(p[1])
            final.append(d)
print(final)  

Result:
[['Dave', 3, 'Red', 9, 7],
 ['Dave', 4, 'Red', 9, 7],
 ['Dave', 2, 'Blue', 9, 2],
 ['Sue', 4, 'Red', 8, 5],
 ['Sue', 1, 'Red', 8, 5],
 ['Sue', 3, 'Yellow', 8, 3]]
```

Comment: THANK YOU @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ! This is EXACTLY what I needed. The code has been implemented already and works beautifully.

Comment: Looks like I need to sort the data first before grouping like this:
`userDays=[[k, sum(v[1] for v in g)] for k, g in groupby(sorted(data), key = lambda x: x[0])]`

Otherwise I'm getting duplicated rows in the final set.

Answer (score 2):

use dictionary for improved performance

```
data = [['Dave', 3, 'Red'], ['Dave', 2, 'Blue'], ['Sue', 4, 'Red'], ['Dave', 4, 'Red'], ['Sue', 1, 'Red'], ['Sue', 3, 'Yellow']]
sum_dict = {}
for d in data:
    sum_dict[d[0]] = sum_dict.get(d[0], 0) + d[1]
    sum_dict[(d[0], d[2])] = sum_dict.get((d[0], d[2]), 0) + d[1]

for d in data:
    d.append(sum_dict[d[0]])
    d.append(sum_dict[(d[0], d[2])])
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're doing sums, this can also be solved nicely with `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [['Dave', 3, 'Red'], ['Dave', 4, 'Red'], ['Dave', 2, 'Blue'], ['Sue', 4, 'Red'], ['Sue', 1, 'Red'], ['Sue', 3, 'Yellow']]


user_days = Counter()
project_user_days = Counter()

for (name, num_days, project) in data:
    user_days[name] += num_days
    project_user_days[(name, project)] += num_days

derived_data = [
    [name, num_days, project, user_days[name], project_user_days[(name, project)]]
    for (name, num_days, project) in data
]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(derived_data)

# [['Dave', 3, 'Red', 9, 7],
#  ['Dave', 4, 'Red', 9, 7],
#  ['Dave', 2, 'Blue', 9, 2],
#  ['Sue', 4, 'Red', 8, 5],
#  ['Sue', 1, 'Red', 8, 5],
#  ['Sue', 3, 'Yellow', 8, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Efficient Code

```
import itertools

def group_data(input1:list)->list:
    name_dict = {k : sum(v[1] for v in g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(input1, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])}
    name_colour_dict = {k: sum(v[1] for v in g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(input1, key=lambda x:(x[0], x[2])), key=lambda x:(x[0],x[2]))}

    for row in input1:
        name = row[0]
        name_colour = (row[0], row[2])
        row.append(name_dict[name])
        row.append(name_colour_dict[name_colour])

    print(input1)

group_data([['Dave', 3, 'Red'], ['Dave', 4, 'Red'], ['Dave', 2, 'Blue'], ['Sue', 4, 'Red'], ['Sue', 1, 'Red'], ['Sue', 3, 'Yellow']]
```

)